# Use controllers globally in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I'm new to Grails and am trying to build a CMS with it.
I want the navigation menu to read from the database so a new page will automatically get a link in the navigation. I've been reading [Grails: use controller from index.gsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279134/grails-use-controller-from-index-gsp) and related questions, but the answers don't seem to work for me. :(

I've created a domain class named Navigation and a template called _header.

In the "Navigation/list" namespace everything works fine, but outside I can't get to the Navigation data.

I've setup url mapping like so:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }
        "/"(controller : "Navigation", action : "list")
        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. Any clues on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the problem all wrong, urlmapping only made the index.gsp redirect to navigation/list. What I was looking for was the

```
DomainClass.findAll( String query )
```

propertie to use in the g:each tag

```
<g:each in="${Navigation.findAll('from Navigation as n where n.css=?', ['ctBoven'])}" var="oNavigation" status="i">
```

This allows me to read any database from any page.

Answer (score 1):

You have two mappings for "/", your new one and the original one: "/"(view:"/index") - for starters you'll need to remove the other one.

Comment: As i remove the "/"(view:"index") it stops redirecting to the index page, result: an error saying "The requested resource (/MyDomain/) is not available."

Comment: `Navigation` should be `navigation`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are aware of this, but there is an open source CMS built in Grails called [Weceem](http://www.weceem.org). If you need to use it as part of another Grails application, there is also a [grails plug in for Weceem](http://www.grails.org/plugin/weceem), so you can use it as part of your app.

It might worth looking into it before building a complete new CMS :-)